# window.showModalDialog not appear when running with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

In java web application there's a line of code which opens a popup window whenever clicking on a link and this window has ok/cancle button:

```
return window.showModalDialog("popupWindow", obj, sFeatures);
```

I use below code in selenium to click on the link

```
geckoDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@onclick, 'return openlink(8251')]")).click();
```

I'm sure the link is clicked successfully but the `window.showModalDialog` does not open and I can not go on because of that.

What is the problem?

Note that I use gecko driver and I also test my application with `chromeDriver` and `ieDriver` with no success

Html tag:

```
<td width="80" aria-describedby="grdOpeningTrustCartable_" title="openning" style="text-align:center;" role="gridcell">
<a class="gridHighlight" onclick="return openLink(8251,'04/12/17 15:50:00')" href="javascript:void(0);">openning</a>
</td>
```

Comment: please post the html of <a> tag; then I'll be able to help you.

Comment: @kushal I Edit the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JavaScript Exceutor` to overcome this problem; given that your click is a working but not resulting into any action:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("return openLink(8251,'04/12/17 15:50:00');");
```